# In my react app i have a component which is posting to two different tables but when i press submit button data only goes to 1 of the tables

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

in my react component i am posting to scorecard table and sc_parameter table the selected parameters are being posted to sc_parameters table and everything else to scorecard table  so the data going to the scorecard table when i press submit it but i dont see the selected parameters in the sc_parameter table i have tried everything i can think about

**The component**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Stepper from "../Stepper/Stepper";

const BASE_API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000';

export default function CreateScorecard() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        desc: '',
        slug: '',
        sc_type_id: '',
        bc_component_id: '',
        active: false,
    });

    const [selectedParameters, setSelectedParameters] = useState([]);
    const [selectedParameter, setSelectedParameter] = useState('');

    const handleParameterChange = (event) => {
        const parameter = event.target.value;

        if (!parameter) {
            alert('Please enter a parameter.');
            return;
        }

        setSelectedParameter(parameter);
    };

    const handleAddParameter = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (selectedParameter) {
            setSelectedParameters([...selectedParameters, selectedParameter]);
            setSelectedParameter('');
        }
    };

    const handleRemoveParameter = (parameter) => {
        setSelectedParameters(selectedParameters.filter((p) => p !== parameter));
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;

        if (name === 'scorecardType') {
            const scTypeId = {
                CR: 1,
                RA: 2,
                TokenRanking: 3,
            }[value];

            setFormData((prevData) => ({
                ...prevData,
                [name]: value,
                sc_type_id: scTypeId,
            }));
        } else {
            setFormData((prevData) => ({ ...prevData, [name]: value }));
        }
    };

    const [bcComponents, setBcComponents] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`${BASE_API_URL}/bc_components/`)
            .then((response) => {
                setBcComponents(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }, []);


    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            const formDataWithParameters = {
                ...formData,
            };

            const scorecardResponse = await axios.post(`${BASE_API_URL}/scorecards`, formDataWithParameters);
            const scorecardId = scorecardResponse.data.id;

            const parameterData = selectedParameters.map((parameter, index) => ({
                parameter_no: index + 1,
                name: parameter,
                scorecard_id: scorecardId,
            }));

            const parameterPromises = parameterData.map((parameter) => {
                return axios.post(`${BASE_API_URL}/sc_parameter`, parameter);
            });

            await Promise.all(parameterPromises).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });

            window.location.href = '/home/createScorecard-step2';
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };


    const handleReset = () => {
        setFormData({
            name: '',
            desc: '',
            slug: '',
            sc_type_id: '',
            bc_component_id: '',
            active: false,
        });
        setSelectedParameters([]);
        setSelectedParameter('');
    };

    return (
        <div className="h-full w-9/12 mt-3 py-1 px-1 justify-center mx-80 rounded">
            <Stepper/>
            <form className="mt-10 border-t-2 border-dashed" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="mt-7 flex space-x-5">
                    <label className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mt-2 w-48">Name of Scorecard *</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="p-1 border-2 rounded w-80"
                        name="name"
                        value={formData.name}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-7 flex space-x-5">
                    <label className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mt-2 w-48">Desc of Scorecard</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="p-1 border-2 rounded w-80"
                        name="desc"
                        value={formData.desc}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-5 flex space-x-5">
                    <label className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mt-2 w-48">Slug</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="p-1 border-2 rounded w-80"
                        name="slug"
                        value={formData.slug}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="mt-5 flex space-x-5">
                    <label className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mt-2 w-48">Type of Scorecard *</label><div className="flex items-center">
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        id="option1"
                        name="scorecardType"
                        value="CR"
                        className="form-radio h-5 w-5 text-indigo-600"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="option1" className="ml-2">
                        Credit Rating (CR)
                    </label>
                </div>

                    <div className="flex items-center">
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            id="option2"
                            name="scorecardType"
                            value="RA"
                            className="form-radio h-5 w-5 text-indigo-600"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="option2" className="ml-2">
                            Risk Assessment (RA)
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex items-center">
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            id="option3"
                            name="scorecardType"
                            value="TokenRanking"
                            className="form-radio h-5 w-5 text-indigo-600"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="option3" className="ml-2">
                            Token Ranking
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-5 flex space-x-5">
                    <label className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mt-2 w-48">
                        Blockchain Components *
                    </label>
                    <div className="relative w-80">
                        <select
                            className="block appearance-none w-full bg-white border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded shadow leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                            name="bc_component_id"
                            value={formData.bc_component_id}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        >
                            {bcComponents.map((component) => (
                                <option key={component.id} value={component.id}>
                                    {component.name}
                                </option>
                            ))}
                        </select>

                        <div
                            className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center px-2 text-gray-700">
                            <svg
                                className="fill-current h-4 w-4"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                            >
                                <path
                                    d="M9.293 13.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L14 16.586V5a1 1 0 112 0v11.586l2.293-2.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1.002 1.002 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                                />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-5 flex space-x-5">
                    <label className="block text-gray-700 font-semibold mt-2 w-48">Parameters</label>
                </div>
                <div className="flex mt-5">
                    <label className="block font-semibold mt-2 w-48">
                        Add Parameter
                    </label>
                    <div className="relative w-80 ml-6">
                        <input
                            className="block appearance-none w-full bg-white border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded shadow leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                            type="text"
                            value={selectedParameter}
                            onChange={handleParameterChange}
                        />
                        <button
                            className="absolute right-0 top-0 bottom-0 px-4 py-2 text-white bg-retro rounded-r"
                            onClick={handleAddParameter}
                        >
                            Add
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-5">
                    {selectedParameters.length > 0 && (
                        <div>
                            <h2 className="font-semibold">Selected Parameters:</h2>
                            <div className="flex flex-col rounded space-y-2">
                                {selectedParameters.map((parameter, index) => (
                                    <div key={parameter} className="flex space-x-1">
                                        <label className="p-1 rounded w-40">{`Parameter ${index + 1}`}</label>
                                        <input
                                            type="text"
                                            className="p-1 border-2 rounded w-80"
                                            value={parameter}
                                            readOnly
                                        />
                                        <button
                                            className="px-2 py-1 font-medium text-white bg-red-700 rounded-md"
                                            onClick={() => handleRemoveParameter(parameter)}
                                        >
                                            Remove
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className="mt-5 flex justify-center mx-auto w-72 py-8">
                    <div className="justify-between flex space-x-20">
                        <button
                            className="h-8 w-20 ring-1 ring-blue1 text-blue1 hover:bg-retro hover:text-white rounded transition"
                        >
                            Back
                        </button>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            className="h-8 w-20 ring-1 ring-blue1 text-blue1 hover:bg-retro hover:text-white rounded transition"
                            onClick={handleReset}
                        >
                            Reset
                        </button>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="h-8 w-20 bg-blue1 text-white hover:bg-black1 rounded transition text-center"
                        >
                            <h1 className="mt-1">Continue</h1>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```